# Using indexPath.row in UITableView in xcode 8 beta 6 won't compile

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, beta

I have a UITableView where I could access the row using indexPath.row in xcode 8 beta 5 and earlier. When I compile the app in beta 6 it says

```
Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout[AggregatedEvents]' (aka 'inout Array<AggregatedEvents>')
```

An example is

```
participant?.Timestamp = String(self.items[indexPath.row].timestamp!)
```

The release notes for beta 6 does not mention changes that relates to this as far as I can see. AggregatedEvents is a struct and participant is an AWS DynamoDB table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assigned the value from indexPath.row to a temporary value and assigned this to the struct. This part of the code compiles with these changes. The original at the bottom.

```
let participant = Participants() // Struct.

let p1: String = String(self.items[indexPath.row].timestamp!)
participant?.Timestamp = p1 as NSString
//participant?.Timestamp = String(self.items[indexPath.row].timestamp!)
```